# Line Chart Hide All Series By Default

Tags: zingchart

I'm using zingchart line chart and I have more than 20 series. When the chart loads it show all series and when i click on one of them it hides.

How can i make all series hide on load by default and show the one i click only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#myChart").hideAllPlots();
```

This solved my issue.